# Retrieving Nested Data from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data from realtime database in a manner that I can display data like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yxPV.png)

Data is stored in this way:

[image]

data should appear like subject then all the tests given under that subject
, then in next cardview another subject and all the tests given under that subject

File where I am trying to fetch data from Firebase

```
package com.gov.thecoachinginstitute;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ShowStudentData extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String id;
    private ListView showSubjectListView,showMarksListView;
    private HashMap<String,String> marksHashMap;
    TextView st_id,st_name,st_schoolName;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    final ArrayList<showDataCustomLayout> subjects = new ArrayList<showDataCustomLayout>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_student_data);


        // Finding Id's
        st_id = findViewById(R.id.st_id);
        st_name = findViewById(R.id.st_name);
        st_schoolName = findViewById(R.id.st_schoolName);
        showSubjectListView = findViewById(R.id.showSubjectListView);
//        showMarksListView = findViewById(R.id.marksListView);

        final ArrayList<showDataCustomLayout> subjectArrayList = new ArrayList<showDataCustomLayout>();





        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("StudentReportLogin",MODE_PRIVATE);

        id = sharedPreferences.getString("ID",null);
        st_id.setText(id);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();



        settingHeaderValues(id);

        showingMarks(id);

    }

    private void showingMarks(String id) {
//        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.student_marks_data_layout,subjects);
        final MarksArrayAdapter adapter = new MarksArrayAdapter(this,subjects);
        databaseReference.child("Student Marks/"+id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                        String subject = ds.getKey();
                        showDataCustomLayout sub = new showDataCustomLayout(subject,subject,subject);
                        subjects.add(sub);
//                        marksHashMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
//                        for (DataSnapshot ds1 : ds.getChildren()){
//                            marksHashMap.put(ds1.getKey(),ds1.getValue(String.class));
//                        }
//                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                        Log.e("sub",subject);
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
//        showSubjectListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        showSubjectListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void settingHeaderValues(String id) {
        databaseReference.child("StudentInfo/"+id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    st_name.setText(snapshot.child("student_Name").getValue(String.class));
                    st_schoolName.setText(snapshot.child("student_School").getValue(String.class));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Custom Adapter

```
package com.gov.thecoachinginstitute;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MarksArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<showDataCustomLayout> {
    public MarksArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<showDataCustomLayout> arrayList) {
        super(context, 0,arrayList);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View currentItemView = convertView;

        if (currentItemView == null){
            currentItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.student_marks_data_show_layout,parent,false);
        }

        showDataCustomLayout currentmarks = getItem(position);

        TextView textView = currentItemView.findViewById(R.id.subjectName);
        textView.setText(currentmarks.getSubject());

        TextView textView1 = currentItemView.findViewById(R.id.test_number);
        textView1.setText(currentmarks.getTest());

        TextView textView2 = currentItemView.findViewById(R.id.test_marks);
        textView2.setText(currentmarks.getNumber());

        return currentItemView;
    }
}
```

Model class

```
package com.gov.thecoachinginstitute;

public class showDataCustomLayout {
    private String subject,test,number;

    public showDataCustomLayout(String subject, String test,String number) {
        this.subject = subject;
        this.test = test;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}
```

Layout File for subject name which includes test marks layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10sp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subjectName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Subject"
                android:textColor="#707BFE"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:padding="5sp"/>

            <include
                layout="@layout/student_marks_data_show_layout"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_number"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Present"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_marks"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Present"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Not getting the expected result

Comment: At first glance, none of the code you shared uses the Firebase Realtime Database API. If you haven't used this API yet, I recommend getting started with https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start, https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that you're using to get data from the Realtime Database.